# How to add a commit date / time to a file

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have a repository at GitHub and update it with TortoiseGit.

I don't want to create version number on every commit / push. But I would like insert a date / time into the Readme.md file before committing automatically.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to include the latest date in the committed README.md? Or what's to goal of this?

Comment: I would like to have a timestamp of the commit time inside the Readme.md in the repository at GitHub.

Comment: It's *technically* possible to do this sort of thing with smudge and clean filters.  But it's a very bad idea; don't.

Comment: @torek : I posted a possible answer, not sure what's bad about it? Can you please comment ?

Comment: @chinmay: that's likely to work. I have experimented with pre-commit hooks modifying the commit, and they do work since Git 1.8 or so. I did not like the side effects very much though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in the pre-commit hook placing a below file, modifying the .sample file, located in `/.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample`. and renaming it to `pre-commit`.

Something like this

```
   #!/bin/sh
   #
   # An example hook script to verify what is about to be committed.
   # Called by "git commit" with no arguments
   # blah...
   date >> README.md
   git add README.md
   echo "Updated the time in README"
   exit 0
```

So every time you make a commit using `git commit`, README.md file will be update with the time.
P.S: You can improve the `date` command using `sed` to update the time, the ex. here just updates it every time you commit.
Also, this will only work if you're using `GIT BASH` desktop app.

Comment: Are you sure that shell-scripts work with TortoiseGit, which is an ms-windows program?

Comment: oops, it will not. have to use `git bash`. Thanks for pointing it out.